How to check if there is an upper collision in pygame,python
I have a ping pong game.And if the circle touches the top of the rectangle, then the circle changes its direction.how can I implement this?
I tried to use coliderest, but it fixes contact with the entire rectangle, but I only need it with the top colirest
